# How to get the username to be the cookie on the next page in PHP?

Tags: php, html

```
$msg = '';
if (isset($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) 
{
  if ($_POST['username'] == 'jacdevs' && $_POST['password'] == '1234') 
  {
    $_SESSION['valid'] = true;
    $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
    $_SESSION['username'] = 'jacdevs';
    echo 'You have entered a valid use name and password';
    echo "<a href ='index.php'>TEST</a>";
  }else {
    $msg = 'Wrong username or password';
  }
}
```

I am having issues with getting the user login in name to be the value of the cookie on the next page. So in my php_login.php file above, when you login you have a text appears on the page telling the login was valid. I also tried to get submit button to go the index page on a successful login but couldn't now I'm just trying to get the user to be the value of the cookie

```
$dbusername='someuser';
$db='somedb';
$dbpassword='password';

$cookie_name='Jeopardy';
$cookie_value= $dbusername;
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day

function getdbHandle()
{
    global $dbusername,$dbpassword,$db;

   if (!($link=mysql_connect("localhost",$dbusername,$dbpassword)))
   {
      echo "Error connecting to the database server.";
      exit();
   }
   if (!mysql_select_db($db,$link))
   {
      echo "Error connecting to the database on the server.";
  exit();
   }
   return $link;
}
```

Comment: echo 'Hello '.($_COOKIE['username']!='' ? $_COOKIE['username'] : 'jacdevs'); // Hello jacdevs!

Comment: Please note that the `mysql_*` functions have been **deprecated since 2013** (in PHP 5.5), and are **removed as of PHP 7** (released 2015). This is because they have **serious** security vulnerabilities. **DO NOT USE THEM**. Please consider upgrading your PHP and switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead, ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) :)

Comment: Are you using a DB? Looks like your values are just static in PHP. Do you start the session? Why store a cookie instead of a session value? Why store the mysql user, sounds like a security hole.

Comment: Why are you trying to store this in a cookie when it's already in the session? Just use `session_start()` then you can echo `$_SESSION['username']`